# psycopg2 + stored procedure + compound type

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I have a stored procedure in PostgreSQL that takes a `t_document` composite type defined as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE t_document AS (
    title    text,
    metadata text,
    data     text
);
```

The stored procedure takes other arguments as well, with a signature like:

```
CREATE or REPLACE  FUNCTION sp_insertItem
(
    name varchar(100) ,
    phone varchar(100) ,
    address varchar(150) ,
    document t_document 
)
```

Calling this stored procedure from another stored procedure looks like this:

```
sp_insertItem('Name','Phone', 'Address', row('Title', 'Metadata', 'Data'));
```

I know I can call procedures using `cursor.callproc` and give the required arguments. However,  I don't know how to pass compound arguments like `t_document`. So how do I call a stored procedure from psycopg2 that expects a compound type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `name`, `phone`, and `address` in a tuple, eventually with an explicit cast to better disambiguate:

```
cur.execute("sp_insertItem(%s, %s, %s, %s::t_document)",
    ['Name', 'Phone', 'Address', ('Title', 'Metadata', 'Data')])
```

You could also use a namedtuple: it is adapted the same way.

```
Document = namedtuple('Document', 'title metadata data')
```